# How can use the hstore extension type when migrating OSM data to PostGreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, openstreetmap, hstore, osm2pgsql

I am trying to migrate some Open Street Maps `.osm.pbf` file to my `postgresql` database using `osm2pgsql` on an ubuntu machine.

When I inspect the data after the process has been finished, the column for `tags` is types as `text[]` and filled with data like this:

```
{highway,residential,lit,yes,name,"St. Nicholas Street",name:en,"Saint Nicholas Street",name:mt,"Triq San Nikola"}
```

---

**Question 1:**

- Is that an `hstore` type data? I can't seem to query it as if so. I tried this format:

```
SELECT * FROM planet_osm_ways WHERE tags ? 'highway' LIMIT 20;
```

yealding this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text[] ? unknown
LINE 1: ...T *, tags as tags FROM planet_osm_ways WHERE tags ? 'highway...
```

---

**Question 2:**

- So assuming the error and format above means that the data was simply not saved as an `hstore` typed data, how can I correct my migration process to fix this?

My process:

1. Create a new database using pgAdmin 3 on linux ubuntu.
2. add hstore extension to database (pgAdmin)
3. add postgis extension to database (pgAdmin)
4. super user into postgres user in terminal

```
osm2pgsql -c -d <DB_NAME> <FILE_PATH> --slim --hstore --multi-geometry
```

5. run migration command:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

That's it, `osm2pgsql` does it's thing and gives out a successful output.

So what am i missing in this process?